# How to calculate combined experience

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following in a function:

```
    edu = sorted(context.education, key=lambda studied: studied["studied_to"], reverse=True)
    #print edu[0].studied_to

    job_history = []
    for job in context.job_history:
        if edu[0].fields_of_study in job.industries:
            from_ = job.from_
            to_ = job.to_
            industries = job.industries
            rd = rdelta.relativedelta(to_, from_) # get date difference 
            # I suspect that combined exp calculation would be done here.
            experience = "{0.years} Years {0.months} Months".format(rd) #get Year - Month format
            #print experience
            job_history.append({"job_title": job_title,
                           "company_name": company_name,
                           "from_": from_,
                           "to_": to_,
                           "industries": industries,
                           "experience": experience})

    j = sorted(job_history, key=lambda s: s["to_"])
    #print j[0]["job_title"]
    return {"relocate_list": provinces,
            "disabilities_dict": disabilities,
            "industries_list": industry_dict,
            "job_history_sorted": j,
            "education_sorted": edu}
```

I can get the experience from each job with the code above. Is there a way to calculate the combined experience.

Currently, say the user has/had more than one job in the IT industry for arguments sake, The above code will give me e.g. `1 Years 0 Months` and `1 Years 4 Months`.

How can I calculate the combined experience so the above example would be `2 Years 4 Months`?

I have tried:

```
rd += rd
```

But this adds the same date, i.e.

```
 1 Years 4 Months + 1 Years 4 Months
```

would output:

```
2 Years 8 Months
```

Comment: I want to take two `year - month` values and add it together. i.e. as in my question above: a user has 2 entiries: `1 Years 4 Months` and `1 Years 0 Months`. This is calculated with:`rd = rdelta.relativedelta(to_, from_) 
            experience = "{0.years} Years {0.months} Months".format(rd)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a new variable to save the relative deltas and display it outside the loop, say:

```
job_history = []
total_exp = rdelta.relativedelta()
for job in context.job_history:
    if edu[0].fields_of_study in job.industries:
        from_ = job.from_
        to_ = job.to_
        industries = job.industries
        rd = rdelta.relativedelta(to_, from_) # get date difference 
        total_exp += rd
        job_history.append({"job_title": job_title,
                       "company_name": company_name,
                       "from_": from_,
                       "to_": to_,
                       "industries": industries,
                       "experience": experience})
 # I suspect that combined exp calculation would be done here.
 experience = "{0.years} Years {0.months} Months".format(total_exp) #get Year - Month format
 #print experience
```

Comment: I just moved the `experience = "{0.years} Years {0.months} Months".format(total_exp)` inside the loop so that when appending `"experience": experience` don't give me an error. Thanks for your answer though `:)`